# How I add attachments on comment in Atlassian.Jira library?

Tags: c#, jira

I need to export my issues to Jira.

I exporting comments but can't export comment's attachments.

```
issue.AddAttachment(noteFile.Name, noteFile.Contents);
```

This code directly adds to the issue.

How do I add these attachments to comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JIRA adds attachments to issues, not comments.